# How can I make a zoomable and scrollable area in web

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an arena that can be zoomed and scrolled as the code blocks on this site are thrown or is there a specific name for this? Thanks in advance for your help.

[text](https://edukits.co/code)

Provide a short example of how to do this, or if they have a specific name for me to investigate how this is done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.